# SUMIFS Across Multiple Worksheets - Need to fix #REF! error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to perform a SUMIFS across multiple worksheets.  I found a couple of formulas online, and pieced together the Formula below. I can't seem to fix the #REF error that came with it.  Do you have any advise on how best to resolve the problem?

I have reviewed each sheet to make sure I am referencing the same information across all sheets.  I've set columns to text or Accounting as necessary.  Not sure what else I can try.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&2011:2019&"'!J:J"),INDIRECT("'"&2011:2019&"'!C:C"),$B3,INDIRECT("'"&2011:2019&"'!E:E"),2))
```

I am expecting to see the Sum of Column J for all sheets given 2 constraints.
Text in Column C:C (All Sheets 2011-2019) must equal the text in Cell $B3, and the number value in column E:E (All Sheets 2011-2019) must be 2.

I am getting the #REF error instead.

Comment: Try putting your sheet names in a range of cells and name the range: `mySheets` then replace all the `2011:2019` to `mySheets`.  I have had better luck doing that instead.

Comment: That didn't do it.  SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&mySheets&"'!J:J"),INDIRECT("'"&mySheets&"'!C:C"),$B3,INDIRECT("'"&mySheets&"'!E:E"),2))

Comment: You listed the sheets in a range and named the range mySheets?  If that did not work then we will not be able to help fix as it has to do with your data or setup not the formula.

Comment: Figured it out.  The text string that I was looking for wasn't on all of the sheets.  It was only on the first 6 sheets.